# Как создать задачу в планировщике задач Windows?

Tags: windows, golang

Каким образом можно добавить задачу в планировщик задач Windows (task scheduler)?

Было бы круто реализовать это без лишних либ.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого Microsoft предоставляет целое семейство [Task Scheduler Interfaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-2-0-interfaces). Поскольку их использование не совсем тривиально, стоит также познакомиться с примерами использования [Using the Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/using-the-task-scheduler).